# How to display listview items using background threads in android

Tags: android, listview

I read the data from `webService` and display in `listview`, I will take much when data is big. Is there any possibility to display data one by one like list view using threads?

Comment: use android `AsyncTask` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: There are tons of resources out in the Internet on this topic. Please search before you post... http://goo.gl/QsdOw

Comment: Yes i used to async tack  DjHacktorReborn but problem is after parsing the content the listview displayed